# Clip iframe inside div with overflow:hidden (Chrome only)

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, overflow, css-position

I have an iframe inside div. The iframe is absolutely positioned beyond the div's bounds. I would like to clip the iframe by adding overflow: hidden to the div, however it shifts the iframe inside the div instead of hiding it.

The problem appears in Chrome, works as expected in Firefox.

```css
#container {  
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: black 1px solid;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nested {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 350px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <iframe id="nested" src="https://wikipedia.org/">  
  </iframe>
</div>
```

**Workaround:** remove `position: absolute` rule from nested iframe and add `display: none` instead. Then set `position: absolute` and remove `display: none` after some time in JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#nested").css({
        display: "",
        position: "absolute"
    });
}, 300);
```

The 300 ms delay is not enough sometimes.

Comment: Missing semi-colon after `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: Nah, missing semicolon is ok in this case. Updated the question, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @nathanallen since you already have a workaround, you are looking for the reason other than a solution here, right?

Comment: definitely a bug. flipping display:block and display:none (and display:inherit) in the inspector, i can even make the iframe disappear *except* for the overflowing parts. looks very weird.